# JAVA apache common CSV

Tags: java

Есть класс который записывает список процессов в Stringbuilder, можно ли как-то не записывать часть процессов, которые я укажу, каким либо образом. Например мне не нужны стандартные процессы windows, как их игнорировать?

```
public static class List {
    public static StringBuilder list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\" + "tasklist.exe /FO CSV");
            try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
                CSVFormat.EXCEL
                        .parse(input)
                        .getRecords()
                        .stream()
                        .map(r -> r.get(0)).forEach(item -> b.append(item + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: кстати зачем у вас статический класс со статическим методом?

Comment: не помню по какой причине, но иначе класс не работает либо не возвращает ничего

Comment: предположу, что это вложенный класс. а почему метод просто не вынести во внешний класс?

Comment: да, класс вложенный. когда метод был во внешнем классе, я не смог получать данные которые возвращает метод. почему так не знаю, но когда сделал в текущем виде все заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static Set<String> exclude = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("systemProcess1", "systemProcess2"));


.map(r -> r.get(0))
.filter(item -> !exclude.contains(item))
.forEach(item -> b.append(item + "\n"));
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю, где тут можно добавить процессы, которые будут игнорироваться? если речь пойдет не о стандартных процессах?

Comment: Имена игнорируемых процессов известны? Занесите их в `Set` и фильтруйте по нему, в чем проблема то?

Comment: имена известны, все дошло) спасибо